# Children and their parents

Tags: characters, dialogue, screenwriting

For those from the USA, any idea at which age children switch from calling their parents, mommy, and daddy to mom and dad. I know there is no specific year-age, but at least some sort of age like 6-8, or 8-10?
I am asking because I never know if a character should address his parent mom or mommy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google would be a more suitable place to search for this kind of information. Did you do thorough research elsewhere before posting your question here? Either way, 'writers' is probably not the right place to ask this, since it is about behaviour in children/young people/adults, and not about writing in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't relate to writing, and is therefore not suitable for this section.

Comment: You might try Parents SE, but honestly there's no real rule. I know some adults who still call their parents Mommy and Daddy, and I never used those terms even as a child. It varies according to culture, nationality, geography, background, and parental preference.

Comment: It would be good if you gave us more information about the character you are interested in knowing about.

Answer (score 2):

I'll weigh in here because "storbror" is totally wrong. There is no global or cultural rule as to how children address their parents.

Parental and peer address implies characterisation and back story.

1) A female teen refers to her mother as "Mommie Dearest"  . . . What does the address tell you about the relationship?

2) A male teen addresses his father as "sir" - What can you glean from this?

3) Suzanne gave birth to Katrina at age 14. The characters refer to each other as "Sue" and "Kat". What is the practical nature of their relationship?

Comment: What part of this answer (or my comments) makes me totally wrong? You are tackling a part of the topic that was not mentioned in the original question nor my comment on it. I never said there was a global or cultural rule either.

Comment: Just to be clear; You are referring to what we can deduct about the characters and their relationships based on how they refer to each other - I think that part of your answer is fine. The question was searching for a factual statistical answer, which led to my comment. In my opinion, those are two very different areas.

Comment: @ storbor. You are 'totally wrong' in your assertion that the question is invalid on the basis the question was not about writing - I simply pointed out that it was.

Comment: I obviously wasn't "totally wrong", since several others voted the question off-topic as well. Your answer is probably relevant or useful to other readers/writers, but that doesn't change the fact that you answered something that the original question didn't actually ask for. Statement that I'm totally wrong is not logical, and furthermore seems unnecessarily arrogant. If you disagree with a comment, write your disagreement in the appropriate section, or make it clear how you disagree.

Comment: Sorry, but just cost other people agree with you doesn't mean you are not totally wrong. e.g. Me and friends are pro-choice therefore it is a fact that abortion is totally wrong. You objected to the question on the basis that it was off-topic. I explained to you and others why the question was valid - end of subject. And now you're really reaching by claiming my comment was in the wrong box . . . really?

Comment: Calling me out in your answer like that seemed unnecessary to me, which was my initial problem. Your tone and how you argue your statements, that is the main issue, not necessarily where you write what. And people agreed with me based on the rules of the site. You saw something else in the question and that's fine, but you state your answer like it's fact, and I clearly didn't. No part of your answer actually explains how I'm wrong.

Comment: By your own logic, just because you and a few others believe this question to be on-topic does not make it on-topic. The question CAN be edited into a question about writing, but in its current state (and in my opinion) it simply is not.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR: There is no universal rule**

I do not think there is a universal rule as to when children change from mommy/daddy to mom/dad.

From my experience (I have 3 children) this shift often begins around the time they start school and is often a progressive thing. Younger siblings tend to do this earlier.

However, some children are "shmoozier" than others and will keep the "mommy/daddy" longer when they want something. Girl tend to keep "Daddy" longer and move to "mom" earlier. And the reverse for boys.

So, this shift will tell the reader more about the character than about society.